# How to remove all Zorin Default themes

Tags: xfce, theme, defaults, zorin

I wanted a lightweight Linux Distro which when researching about it, I found XFCE to be lightweight but it looked ugly, but when I saw Zorin Lite edition looking good, I thought - It looks good and lightweight - So I installed it. But now I'm going to change Distros so that I can try many but not now. I'm wondering how to safely remove all the Zorin Themes for XFCE and make it look default because I want to experience the XFCE-ness and I want to install other themes and icon packs. Is there a way to safely uninstall all XFCE themes which came with Zorin Lite. Or is those themes and look default and not removable. Or is that themes but not safe to uninstall. I have a lots of questions like this though. My only thing is make Zorin Lite look and be like an XFCE Default Desktop Environment and how do I do that

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: XFCE is a Desktop Environment (DE), not a distro, whereas the distro Zorin Lite is essentially Ubuntu with a highly customized XFCE DE. The purpose of Zorin OS is to provide a distro with a "user-friendly" user interface; see their [About](https://zorinos.com/about/) page. Making Zorin Lite look like XFCE would be a lot of work to basically get Ubuntu with default XFCE. The easiest way to get that would be to switch distros from Zorin to [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/), which has a default XFCE setup out-of-the-box. Then you could install whatever theme, icon pack, or whatnot that you want.

Comment: @DavidYockey I know that XFCE is an DE and all other few things. My thing is How do I safely remove the Zorin Theme which is applied in this Distro. Actually in Pling and xfce-look I found "Zorin Default" theme. So I wondered whether I can remove the Zorin Theme and make it look like XFCE and add my custom other themes.